# Troubleshooting SCSS/CSS files not being found from gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to implement the [`bootstrap_forms`](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/bootstrap_form) gem. The gem is installing fine, and I can use the ruby methods in my views and they work great. The CSS however isn't importing. My app was created using bootstrap at project initialization, so my style imports are in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss`:

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';

@import 'rails_bootstrap_forms';
```

My IDE, however, highlights this third import as invalid and when I try to restart my dev server with `bin/dev` I see the following when I load a page:

```
| Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
|   ╷
| 4 │ @import 'rails_bootstrap_forms';
|   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|   ╵
```

I have even gone into the directory where the gem is installed and I can find the expected CSS file at `app/assets/stylesheets/rails_bootstrap_forms.css`.

What might I be missing and/or what other tests can I run to find out where the failure in this import is occurring?

Comment: What version of Rails?

Comment: The project is currently running 7.0.8

Comment: What is the file's actual name? I found I had to do something like name the file `rails_bootstrap_forms.css.scss` and then the import had to be `@import "rails_bootstrap_forms.css.scss"`. The exact extension may not be critical, but I did have to use the entire name in the `@import...` call.

Comment: The file is `rails_bootstrap_forms.css`, which I could have sworn I tried before posting this question, but I just tested again and it works? I may have had something cached that restarting the server fixed? Either way, thanks for the advice.